# PHP Searching with first and last name

Tags: php, search, wamp

my project partner and I are relatively new to PHP and needed some help in searching through multiple columns. We are trying to have a functioning search bar that returns the name and corresponding youtube url of a comedian depending on the first and last name that was searched. We got it to work with first name OR last name being searched but not with both of them. (i.e Sarah or Silverman will work but not Sarah Silverman) We tried changing the clause to AND but that did not work at all. Below is our search code. 
The line

```
$searchdb = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * 
                                FROM comedian 
                                WHERE fname LIKE '%$searchq%' 
                                OR lname LIKE '%$searchq%'") 
        or die ("Could not search.");
```

is what we are trying to modify.Thank you!

```
 <?php
session_start();

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die("Could not connect");

mysqli_select_db($con, 'youtube') or die(mysqli_error($con));
$output = '';

if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    //Will replace everything that is not a letter or number with blank.
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

    $searchdb = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * 
                                    FROM comedian 
                                    WHERE fname LIKE '%$searchq%' 
                                    OR lname LIKE '%$searchq%'") 
            or die ("Could not search.");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($searchdb);

    if($count == 0){
        $output = 'There were no search results.';
        print("$output");
    }else{
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($searchdb)){
            //Variables
            $fname = $row['fname'];
            $lname = $row['lname'];
            $comedianid = $row['comedianid'];

            //Output first and last name
            $output .= '<div> <b>Comedian:</b> '.$fname.' '.$lname.'</div>';



            //Matching comedian with respective video URL using about table relation.
            $searchdb2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM about WHERE comedianid LIKE '%$comedianid%'") or die ("Could not find a video by this author.");
            //Fetches comedian id from about table
            $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($searchdb2);
            $url = $row2['url'];

            $outputvid = preg_replace("#.*youtube\.com/watch\?v=#","",$url);
            $outputvid = '<iframe width="700" height="600" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$outputvid.'"></iframe>';


            print("$output");   
            print("$outputvid");

            $output = '';
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you have a backtick at the end of the first line?

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: If `comediamid` is a numeric like `1,2,3....` then use `=` rather than LIKE

Comment: Oops i fixed the backtick thing

Comment: So what is actually wrong, as far as you can tell?

Comment: Just to confirm.. If I search for Sarah, it works because it is the first name? If I search for Silverman it works too? But if you type in Sarah Silverman it is not working?

Comment: Thats because you will be searching for `%Sarah Silverman%` in a column that only contains either `Sarah` OR `Silvername` :)

Comment: Yes correct! Nothing is wrong with the code per say but it does not return a value if i search both first and last name together separated by a space. It only works if i search either or

Comment: In other words `Sarah Silverman` does not exist in either of the columns

Comment: You could try splitting the input on space... But that is rather unreliable as what happens when you want to search for `Michael J Fox`???? So enter the First name and Last name in seperate fields in your form

Comment: You're right! Is there a way I can make that work without modifying the columns?

Comment: Its not a form really, its a search bar so I cannot split it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the first and last name and then search based on that string...

```
SELECT * 
FROM comedian 
WHERE fname ||  ' ' || lname LIKE '%Sarah Silverman%'
```

This will show "Sarah Silverman", even though Sarah is stored in `fname` and Silverman in `lname`

**Edit**: I have tested it in SQLite, you might have to change `||` to `+` based on your database management system.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but instead put '$searchq' after LIKE and it output that there were no search results. I'm not sure why?

Comment: @Hafsa Please but %$searchq% and try again. 

Make sure you type the correct name, with lower and upper case. You might add that later in your query aswell.

Comment: Are you using MySQL? MYSQL uses CONCAT function instead of || or +. Use that CONCAT(fName, " ", lName)

Comment: Yup! I am using MySql

Comment: Should i try 
SELECT * 
FROM comedian 
WHERE  CONCAT(fname," ",lname) LIKE '%search%';

Comment: @Hafsa Yes please try :) Report back if it didnt work

Comment: Hello! I was wondering if you had an idea on how to answer my latest question? You were very helpful last time

Comment: @Hafsa Just checked it out, but it is not available anymore